# In a Rails form, can select options be saved to the database as a hash?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Let's say I have the following select boxes in my form for a `Gate` object:

```
f.select(:type_use, options_for_select([['Enter & Exit', 8],
                                        ['Only Enter', 4],
                                        ['Only Exit', 4],
                                        ['Only Enter for visitors', 2],
                                        ['Only Exit for visitors', 2]],
                                        @gate.type_use),
                                        { :include_blank => '- select -' },
                                        { :class => 'form-control'})
```

These options will never change.  The integers like 4 and 8 represent the number of cycles per day, and I later use these integers to do calculations.  However I still want to retain the correct string labels for each integer for use in my view, so i can show that a gate has an 'Only Exit' type of use, for example.

So, is it possible to save select options as a hash, or does Rails have some other way to map integers to strings for use in my application?

Previously what i've been doing is just saving the string values, and then using `if` statements, manually assigning to a variable the corresponding integer based on the string value, before doing calculations.  But I have yet to discover a more efficient and elegant way to do this.

In my research I did find information about Enums, but I don't think it applies to this situation because I have duplicate integers and Enums seem more like sequential indexes to me.  Also it seems that other questions about hashes in select boxes have revolved around populating options for select with a hash, rather than saving as a hash

Comment: Given that you said "these options never change" why would you want to store this in the database... might I suggest defining a constant in some initializer? e.g. constants.rb?

Comment: not sure i completely follow...each `gate` will have one of these 5 options selected.  that selection needs to be saved.  I don't have to save both the  string and integer values, that is true.  But i need to save at least one.

Comment: hstore is probably what you want do RE below. I'm just saying I don't understand why you want to store the strings in the DB when you could just have some sort of constant that tells you "oh, 2 means 'Only enter for visitors'", but the problem is you seem to have multiple IDs mapping to the same string...

Answer (score 1):

You can save `Hash` and `Array` by using [Serialize](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/serialize/class) on the `Model` you want to save the `Hash` or `Array`

Ex:

```
class User < Active::Record

  serialize :data, Hash           # for hash
  serialize :other_data, Array    # for array

end
```

There is also a `DataType` called `hstore` in postgres that allows you to save `Hash` data and then be able to perform searches and index items in the `Hash`

To use it you first have to enable the `hstore` extension and then use it in your migrations

```
.... add_column :data_set, :hstore, default: {}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer... Given that I use Postgres, is the hstore option preferred?

Comment: The best option right now seems to be `Postgres jsonb`. Here is a link to read about it: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/115825/jsonb-with-indexing-vs-hstore#115849